# Terminal keeps on killing a node server

Tags: command-line, server

I am running NextJS dev server on my ubuntu terminal and my terminal keeps on killing it after like 5 mins.
I am running Ubuntu completely and not as dual boot. My Ram is 8 gigs.

I tried setting the overcommit ratio to 2 (as per some suggestions I found online) but it's still the same issue. Checked why the process was killed and it says 'out of memory'

Here is the `htop` screenshot:

[image: htop logs - screenshot]

Comment: Please provide some debugging information like taking a screenshot of a running instance of ```htop``` or try giving some RAM Details.

Comment: @RishonJR I have edited the qn already

Comment: If it says out of memory, then you're out of memory. 8G is not a lot of RAM these days, especially not if you are also running a memory-hog like chrome.

Comment: Do you *need* Chrome running?  If not, close it, thats one of your memory consumers.  8GB is also very small if you are running memory hogging programs and dev/server platforms that need space.  Its why my systems all have 16GB or more in them.

Comment: chrome just makes your system scream. just switch to Firefox and your good to go. that error won't popup anymore. or else try ```CTRL``` + ```ALT``` + ```F3``` to enter ```tty3``` mode. note that once you enter ```tty3``` you will have to restart the ```gdm3``` service or reboot your computer.

Comment: @ThomasWard I get the part where chrome eats a lot of RAM, but its just like 5 tabs running. But maybe i have less ram or sth. The weird part is this behaviour wasnt there when I was using windows 11.

Comment: @RishonJR let me try it and see how it goes. Thanks !!

Comment: @Tony__ keep in mind that Windows and Linux are apples and oranges.  You also have to keep an eye on the GUI itself, Ubuntu vanilla uses GNOME/Wayland and that's not memory light either.  As you saw, you already are hovering at 4GB of 8GB used, so you're still staring at that "memory problem".  And with Windows 11, 8GB is *bare minimum* to operate, 16GB is recommended and probably should be the 'standard' for memory on a system nowadays based on my experience in the systems administration world (this is what I do as a professional)

Comment: @Thomas Ward it's 4-8 GB, not 8-16GB. Ubuntu works fine with my 2 Gigabyte  RAM Setup.

Comment: @RishonJR Desktop or Server?  GNOME has a memory leak problem that *eats* memory the longer it remains online.  2GB is *bare minimum* to run Ubuntu GUI and not effectively at that level (from personal experience)

Comment: @ Thomas Ward Either one. just that Ubuntu desktop is based of ubuntu server. 4GB RAM, Intel Core i5(2nd gen or later), With an Okay graphics card is enough.